# Is there a way to call a function with no () in c++?

Tags: c++, function

I don't have a program. I was just curious if there is any way to call a function that has no args without `()`?

For example instead of

```
function();
```

how can I make it

```
function;
```

Comment: There are a number of ways in C++ to call a function without using `()`.  For example, all operator overrides are called using the respective operator.  And conversion functions are called by code such as the example `S x; T y = x;`

Comment: No, each language has its syntax. In C or C++ calling a function necessarily needs the parenthesis (even if they are empty). The name of a function (without the following parenthesis) refers to its address (to initialise a function pointer for example).

Comment: @ closer with greek letters in the name, this question is about calling a nullary function, that one specifically demanded the ability to pass arguments.

Comment: May I ask for your use case? Do you want to emulate Delphi? If so, good luck with that. I even use parenthesis always in Delphi code also BTW. I hate that feature to omit them.

Comment: @Ben The dupe contained a viable answer, the exact same as was made here BTW. The OP clearly didn't ask about operators or operator overloads.

Comment: This is probably an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Ben Can you write an answer please, how to solve the OPs demand to call `function()` with just `function;` from your proposals in comments? I'd be very interested to learn and know that.

Comment: Technically, `std::invoke(function)` answers the question as stated (with the provision that examples are just examples, not requirements). I suspect you might find that answer unsatisfying though. Could you either say (in the comments) that this answer is acceptable or update your question (not in the comments) with more information regarding your goals (so that `std::invoke` is no longer an answer)?

Comment: @JaMiT I don't think it answers the question. The text is clear that given a function `fn`, OP would like to be able to call it as just `fn` and not `fn()`. Even the title says "no ()". `std::invoke(function);` does indeed have parens -- to invoke `std::invoke`.

Comment: @cdhowie I know it does not answer the question as intended. However, the title says "no ()", not "no parentheses". Technically, "`()`" is an *empty* pair of parentheses. The expression `std::invoke(function)` does not have an empty pair of parentheses, answering the question as written. *For those that missed my point: I am not suggesting this should be an answer. I am suggesting the question be fleshed out more. Perhaps the fleshed out version would inspire answers that focus on explaining what a function name without parentheses currently means, which is probably the real missing info.*

Answer (score 4):

In some cases, functions get called without parens. For example, operator overloads and conversion operators.

However, invoking an arbitrary function in this way is not possible in C++. It would create ambiguities in the language.  In C++, a function name decays to a pointer to the function.

```
int foo();

auto var = foo;
```

With your proposed syntax, this could do one of two things:

- `foo` is invoked and the result is stored in `var`, which has type `int`.
- `foo` decays to a function pointer. The pointer is stored in `var`, which has type `int (*)()`.

Both are reasonable expectations if we allow functions to be invoked without parens. Requiring the parens is the simplest way to avoid this situation.

Comment: Good explanation why that's not implemented. Doesn't really answer the question though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sure it does: _"invoking an arbitrary function in this way is not possible in C++."_ A longer way of saying "no." That's a direct answer to the question "is this possible."

Answer (score 0):

Anything possible with macros:

```
#include <iostream>

void f() { std::cout << "Hello, World!"; }

#define function f();

int main() { function; }
```

Comment: Does what OP asks. But don't do this.

Comment: @eerorika Yup... I don't remember the last time I use macros (other than `#include`s).

Comment: @eerorika why shouldn't i do that?

Comment: Try declaring a type `std::function` after that macro...

Comment: @Duffka Because macros are evil. They are only for advanced programmers who know that it is better to not use them. Only thing this achieves is make the program harder for others to understand, which potentially includes yourself in future when you attempt to modify the program and do something like what Tas mentioned.

Comment: @Duffka One other reason is, they don't rely on scope rules. More on: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Res-macros2

Comment: You can get rid of macros and not having parens in your code by doing `function` then `#include "open_paren.h"` then `#include "close_paren.h` then `;`  The files contain `(` and `)`, but the user won't have to type them.